# Reasons to choose LES in stead of RANS models? (turbulence)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, numerical-modelling

In oceanography, is there any particular reason why choosing large eddy simulations in stead of RANS (regardless of the type of flow)? In both cases, 2d simulations would be used (shallow water model).

What are the pros and contras, in general, of both approaches?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an oceanographer, but meteorologist, but in the atmosphere using LES for 2D simulation is a non-sense. Even more so for a simplified model such as the shallow water equations.

LES to work properly must resolve a big part of the turbulence spectrum and therefore must be able to explicitly simulate the dynamics turbulent flow. In the limit of very large resolution and disabled subgrid model you need the code to approach DNS. You hardly can expect that from 2D shallow water model.

It is true that the Smagorinsky model originated in 2D simulations of atmosphere, but the true correct application proved to be elsewhere.

Comment: So you think using RANS is the best approach? Just because a matter of computing cost? Have you read something about "horizontal large eddy simulations"?

Comment: You may consider some depth-averaged  LES. But you must make sure to capture all the important scales